# Closure deleter in initializer list (C++0x) and compiler warning

Tags: c++11, closures, shared-ptr, unique-ptr, initializer-list

I get a `warning C4355: 'this' : used in base member initializer list` from Visual C++ 2010:

I have a class holding a handle, and I want to automatically close the handle *even if the ctor for the class fails* (so its dtor is not called). However, I don't want to bother making a whole handle-wrapping class, and would rather hold it in a smart pointer.  And so I wrote this:

```
foo.h
~~~~~
class Foo
{
    ...
    Log &_log;
    std::unique_ptr<void, std::function<void (void *)>> _handle;
    ...
}

foo.cpp
~~~~~~~
#include <windows.h>
Foo::Foo(Log &lg, ...) : _log(lg), ... _handle(nullptr, [&](void *h){ if (h) { if (!CloseHandle(h)) LOG(_log, "Could not close port: " << LastWinErr()); h = nullptr; } })
{
    HANDLE h(CreateFile( ...
    if (h == ...
    _handle.reset(h);
    ... // Bunch of other stuff that could potentially throw
}
```

Previously to the closure I was initializing _handle with something like `_handle(nullptr, bind(PortDeleter, placeholders::_1, ref(_log)))`, but that requires a separate definition.

My questions: is the warning a concern for this specific instance? Either way, what is the detailed reason? Is there a trivial way to avoid it?

Comment: Does your lambda have to capture everything (`[&]`)? What happens if you just make it `[]` (or `[&_log]`)?

Comment: Still the same problem, as _log is really this->_log. [&lg] worked though.

Comment: Oh, of course -- you can't access `_log` without `this`, but you _can_ access `lg`. Sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short is, if you pass your `this` pointer around and it's used to access member functions or variables in the initializer list or in the destructor, Bad Things Happen™. If you know that isn't going to happen, then feel free to ignore the warning. Of course, it's also a good warning- if any of the functions or variables that you access in the destructor belong to the class, then this is unsafe, as you may be accessing them prior to their construction/after their destruction. The problem is not critical if you know your initialization/destruction orders, but generally a bad move as this makes maintenance rather fiddly at best. As you could capture the constructor parameter instead, I'd have to recommend that.

Comment: Thanks DeadMG, [&lg] worked. Just out of curiosity, how is the captured parameter stored in this case? Is it in memory associated with the smart pointer? It seems during the lifetime of a Foo object, there would be two copies of lg.

Comment: I suppose it's just like if you wrote `struct Foo { int & a; Foo(int & a) : a(a) { } };`, the reference will be stored somewhere in the function object. Better not use it after the original object goes out of scope!